# How to implement running commands in the background by supporting ‘&’ and wait (for UNIX Shell)?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, operating-system

So my understanding is that if you terminate a command with ‘&,’ it runs the process in the background. If two commands were separated by ‘&,’ they would run simultaneously.
e.g. command1 & command2 //runs simultaneously
To implement this, I would have the shell fork a child process and have the child execute the 1st command I. The background. The parent would not wait and would execute the second command in parallel.
Is this the right approach? And how can I apply this to support wait()?

Comment: "*Is this the right approach*". Sounds right or at least a reasonable general approach without specifics. And what do you mean exactly by "suppory wait"? What command triggers that in your shell and what behaviour follows that? But question is not really suitable for Stack Overflow as it is too vague and open ended. Best to show some code and ask a specific question about that. Please review [ask].

Comment: You might to want to read or refresh about *signal handling*. Especially the `SIGCHLD` signal.

Answer (score 0):

This is using bash on a generic unix:

```
BigMac:tmp steve$ sleep 10 & sleep 13 & sleep 20 &
[1] 69168
[2] 69169
[3] 69170
BigMac:tmp steve$ wait %1; wait 69169; kill %3
[1]   Done                    sleep 10
[2]-  Done                    sleep 13
[3]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 20
```

The first line launches three separate sleeps.   The shell assigns them job numbers `[1], [2], [3]`; whereas the system assigns them process id's `69178,69169,69170` resp.   The commands `wait` and `kill` can take either identifier, as shown in the second line.

The second line waits for the first job `% indicates to the shell that the following number is in its naming scheme`, then waits for the second process `the lack of % indicates a process identifier`, then kills the third job.

There is a lot more to this than such a simple example can convey; particularly the notion of `job` is quite a bit more involved than this example portrays.

`The UNIX Programming Environment` [ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-13-937681-X) despite being nearly 40 years old, provides a great fundamental understanding of how and why UNIX works the way it does.   There are more modern, detailed, and system specific works as well.